# Reverting the question state "answered"

Tags: feature-request

Ich halte es für keine gute Idee, dass man keinen Einfluss darauf hat, welche Antwort zum Schluss mit grünem Häkchen markiert wird, denn das wird dann oft später als die offiziell richtige Antwort angesehen.

Hier sollte entweder die Community ein Mitspracherecht haben oder ein Revert sollte machbar sein.

Bsp.: Der Fragende akzeptiert eine offensichtlich falsche Antwort, weil er einfach glaubt ohne zu wissen, ob das die richtige ist.

---

I think it is not a good idea to not have participation which answer will get the green tickmark in the end, because later that is often appreciated as the right answer.

The community should either have a right to a say in a matter or to be able to revert that.

E.g.: The questioner accepts an obviously wrong answer because of just believing instead of knowing if it is the right one.

Comment: I want to delete this question because it's a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on meta.stackexchange.com and has a duplicate there.

Answer (score 4):

This is part of the [fundamental design of SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

It's a privilege of the OP to reward the answer which helped him personally the most:

> It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him
>   or her personally

The community can and should punish obviously wrong answers through downvotes, comments and/or flags, and guide the asker by providing better or more truthful answers and voting those up, but ultimately the green tick mark is for the OP to give.

There's even a pretty rare badge for providing answers that highly outscore accepted answers: [Populist](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist). Given that, it is extremely unlikely that this is not by design and even less likely to be changed anytime soon.

Edit: In the end, you can only protect users this much from themselves. Truly malicious actions like deliberatly accepting obviously wrong answers may be subject to a flag against the wrong answer. And if the asker is not malicious, she might even change her mark at anytime. Maybe pointing out the mistake in a comment will be enough.

Comment: It could help if the green tick mark was deleted automatically if the vote number of another answer is much higher. Or if the green tick mark is disabled for a few days to give answers a chance to grow with their vote numbers until the truth becomes visible.

Comment: @äüö What exactly would it help with? The definition of the green check mark still would not consider what the community thinks about a particular answer. If a really bad accepted answer gets deleted, it's accepted status is deleted along with it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79582/288176 --- what is it really that bothers you? That accepted answers are by default sorted to the top?

Comment: I suspect the green tick mark is often appreciated as the right answer by later readers of a topic.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature - any similar requests have been declined in the past. The best answer is the most upvoted answer, the one that helped the OP most is the accepted answer. There is a fundamental dfference between these two approaches which should not be reverted by community votes.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Maybe using a green tick mark is misleading then. But that may be my personal feeling. Just a public poll could clarify how it is understood by the people in general.

Comment: Though I'll wait a while to not fall into the trap of accepting too fast (although it's possible) before other answers may come in which could convince me more. :)

Comment: @äüö Sure, that's a good strategy :)

Comment: @Takkat: “The best answer is the most upvoted answer” – Often, the earliest good answer gets the most upvotes, which is not necessarily the best one. Sometimes it’s even the earliest answer that’s not too bad. This effect also discourages posting better answers late. But it’s a general problem of how SE works and I have no solution to propose.

Comment: @Crissov. so true... that's why frequent voting even if it was an old post is so much encouraged.

Comment: @Crissov be glad that this is not SO - Fastest Gun In the West wins, if any at all :D